# Binding a DropDownList without a SqlDataSource in a Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, binding, drop-down-menu

I realize that you can easily set up a dropdownlist in a gridview using a SqlDataSource, but what about a limited list containing only listitems?  Putting a Bind in the selected value does not seem to work without a DataSource.  Here's an example of what I've got so far.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="Fund"  runat="server" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Fund") %>' >
      <asp:ListItem  Value="">---</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="Test1">Test</asp:ListItem>
      <asp:ListItem Value="Test2">Test2</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

It seems like such a stupid little problem to have, to the point where I'm about to just go make a static 10 row table in my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> items= new Dictionary<string, string>();
items.Add("-1","-Select-");
items.Add("Test1", "Test1");
items.Add("Test2", "Test2");
ddl.DataSource = items;
ddl.DataValueField = "Key";
ddl.DataTextField = "Value";
ddl.DataBind();
```

Comment: Where exactly should I be setting this?  I tried in the DropdownList's onDataBinding event, but I'm getting stuck in a loop somewhere.  Edit: I see why it would cause a loop there now.  Stupid lack of forethought on my part there.

Comment: Well, I finally got the DDL added using this code through the RowCreated event, but no databinding with the gridview source is occurring.

Comment: I'm sorry, the problem was totally unrelated and it was just a completely stupid mistake.  It was a new field we were adding to a table and I updated the InsertCommand instead of the UpdateCommand.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to create a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` in the code and bind it to the `DropDownList` or as you mentioned bind it to a static table...

Sample code:

```
Dictionary<string, string> list = new Dictionary<string, string>();
list.Add("item 1", "Item 1");
list.Add("item 2", "Item 2");
list.Add("item 3", "Item 3");
list.Add("item 4", "Item 4");

ddl.DataSource = list;
ddl.DataTextField = "Value";
ddl.DataValueField = "Key";
ddl.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the `DropDownList` programmatically. I would really recommend avoiding the user of the `SqlDataSource` control. It is very clunky and not very good in terms of reuse.

The following piece of code uses the Entity Framework to retrieve data from a database by a user name. Using this function you can bind the needed data to the `DropDownList` without having to create a `SqlDataSource` everytime you need to call this procedure.

```
public List<Record> GetAllRecordsByUserName(string credentials)
{
    List<Record> recordList;
    using (CustomEntities context = new CustomEntities())
    {

        IQueryable<Section> recordQuery = from records in context.Records
                                              where records.UserName == credentials
                                              select records; 
        recordList = recordQuery.ToList<Record>();
    }
    return recordList;
}

public void BindDropDown()
{
    DropDownList1.DataSource = GetAllRecordsByUserName("test.user");
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```